# Seperate query and phrase values for solr query

Tags: solr, lucene

I have to match and boost solr documents with following requirements

- match multiple tokens to multiple fields and score each token independtely
- Use phrase boost only on a particular combination of tokens

Eg:

- Match on tokens - blue AND mens AND shoes AND (nike^2 OR adidas^3)
- Phrase boost on phrase "blue mens"

I can do following to achieve this

- q : blue mens
- fq: shoes
- bq: nike^2, adidas^3

Cons

- shoes is not scored
- documents not matching nike or adidas are also returned

To solve for above I can use

`q = blue AND mens AND shoes AND (nike^2 OR adidas^3)`

but then pf is also applied on "blue mens shoes nike adidas"

So both solutions are half baked. Is there a way I can use a different query for pf and different query for q ?

Comment: Could you use a boost query as a phrase to boost those that match? i.e. `bq="blue mens"^10`? You can also use a dedicated field with a shingle filter attached that only contains those terms/phrases that you want to consider for phrase boosts.